# Magento Custom Module Directory Help

Tags: checkout, blocks, custom

Old user, Noob question!

I have a module which is successfully "trying" to overide the sidebar.html block using the below code.

```
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
          "Magento_Checkout/template/sidebar.html": "MyBrand/MyModule/template/sidebar.html"
        }
    }
};
```

The problem is, I'm not sure where in my module directory to place the actual replacement file ie.

in **`app/code/MyBrand/MyModule or app/design/MyBrand/MyModule`** or somewhere else.

I have tried several places for this file "sidebar.html" and several directory references but no joy. The GET command fails to locate the replacement file. I can't quite understand how Magento sees or starts from when using this directory.

Update command, deploy and cache clear run after every attempt.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

To override an HTML file through RequireJS with the `map` configuration, you should have the following configuration:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Checkout/template/sidebar.html': 'VendorName_ModuleName/template/sidebar.html'
        }
    }
};
```

You can place your `requirejs-config.js` in either your module directory or the `<VendorName>_<ModuleName>` directory within your theme.

- Add your `requirejs-config.js` in your module directory (`app/code/<VendorName>/<ModuleName>/view/frontend/`) to apply the customization to all themes.
- Add your `requirejs-config.js` in the `<VendorName>_<ModuleName>` directory in your theme (`app/design/themeVendor/themeName/<VendorName>_<ModuleName>`) to apply the customization to a specific theme.